# Some object-oriented languages require recompilation of superclasses when compiling subclasses

Tags: oop

I've spend a good day trying to find out a confirmation to this quote, "*Some object-oriented languages are not sufficiently modular and require recompilation of superclasses when compiling subclasses.*"

I've found it in [this](http://doc.cat-v.org/programming/bad_properties_of_OO) article where author was talking about OO languages flaws.

I'm trying to find any information regarding this topic. I tried to google, "Recompilation of superclasses when subclass is changed", "compilation process", and many more.
I'm aware of C++ preprocessor/compiler/linker model and i totaly get it. But how about Java, Python, Ruby, Php, smalltalk and so forth.

What language is not sufficiently modular, as the author says?

Comment: The other way around, "recompilation of *sub*classes when *super*class is changed", would make more sense to me. Intriguing indeed.

Comment: For `Java` see this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/236062

Comment: "But how about Java, Python, Ruby, Php, smalltalk and so forth" will make the question to broad IMHO.

Comment: @bummi i coudln't construct the sentense more properly to get a solid answer.